# Take in input as one string, help fix main so it only asks for one input

Tags: java, string, methods, output

Currently I have a class that shifts the input of a given string to print out an output. The program works fine and has the correct output, however I am not sure how to fix main so that it just needs to ask for one string instead of four separate strings. Please show how you would fix this

example output: WVOGJTXQHUHXICWYYMGHTRKQHQPWKYVGLPYSPWGOINTOFOPMO

the only issues I have is how main asks for four separate inputs, i would like it to only ask for one string, please show how

```
    public class shiftRows {

       public static String Shift(String str, int shiftNum)
       {
           char[] out = new char[4];
           if(shiftNum==1)
           {
               out[0]=str.charAt(1);
               out[1]=str.charAt(2);
               out[2]=str.charAt(3);
               out[3]=str.charAt(0);
           }
           if(shiftNum==2)
           {
               out[0]=str.charAt(2);
               out[1]=str.charAt(3);
               out[2]=str.charAt(0);
               out[3]=str.charAt(1);
           }
           if(shiftNum==3)
           {
               out[0]=str.charAt(3);
               out[1]=str.charAt(0);
               out[2]=str.charAt(1);
               out[3]=str.charAt(2);
           }
           return new String(out);
       }
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {

           Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);

           String[] input=new String[4];

           String[] output=new String[4];

           System.out.println("Enter 4 String's :");
           for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
           {
               input[i]=sc.next();
           }
           output[0]=input[0];
           for(int i=1;i<4;i++)
           {
               output[i]=Shift(input[i],i);
           }

           for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
           {
               System.out.println(output[i]);


             }

       }

}
```

Comment: Is it allowed to change other parts of the code? If you remove the array, all parts of the code have to change as well.

Comment: I mean if anyone knows a better way to fix it. this part of the code This step is the same as the ShiftRows step in the AES encryption. 

It circularly shifts the rows in each block in the following fashion. The first row remains the same. Shift the second row one position to the left. Shift the third row two positions to the left. Finally, shift the fourth row
three positions to the left.

Comment: Please post an example of the input you are giving now, and the input you would like to give instead, to achieve the same output.

Comment: (Input)Enter 4 String's :
WGDT
CHFY
HDYR
ASDF

Output:
WGDT
HFYC
YRHD
FASD

Comment: (Desired input) Enter a string: WGDTCHFYHDYRASDF

Output:
WGDT
HFYC
YRHD
FASD

Comment: I would like the input to be just one string instead of 4 separate strings.
The output should still be the same 4x4 matrices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provides the same output, and uses the input of a single continuous String.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

   String[] input= new String[4];

   String[] output= new String[4];

   // -
   System.out.println("Enter a String");
   String inputStr = sc.next();

   for (int i = 0, n = 0; i < 4; i++, n+=4) {
       input[i] = inputStr.substring(0+n, 4+n);
   }
   // -

   output[0] = input[0];
   for(int i=1; i<4; i++)
   {
       output[i] = Shift(input[i],i);
   }

   for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
   {
       System.out.println(output[i]);
   }

}
```